# Concurrent ServerSocket connections

Tags: java, file-transfer, serversocket

Refer [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/509758/sockets/java/Send-file-network) in Andrey Kozhanov' code.

In Server.java, line 14, method run():

When I send a file "A" and during file transfer start another Client and send other file "B", this last transfer ("B") will block until "A" finishes.

How can I implement a concurrent server receiver?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you not understand? Doesn't seem like you put enough effort into it. This site isn't for walking you through subjects step by step, rather than help you get answers to a *specific* programming problem. Either show an attempt and tell us where you're having problems, or tell us what you are currently having troubles understanding.

Comment: You rude! my `SPECIFIC` problem is not to understand concurrency. Is how to solve a `SPECIFIC` case where a port is busy receiving data and a different connection is incomming. So, thanks @Krab for being `SPECIFIC` and give me the solution. Thanks again for illustrate with some code. All efforts in  world are nothing in front of a good idea.

Comment: I wasn't being rude, or at least not trying to be. I was just telling you how the site works.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are many different ways to create a "concurrent server receiver". You're expected to look into it on your own, give an attempt, then post your problem here once you run into one. I also suggest checking out [link] "*Act as if you're talking to a busy colleague*". No need to be so hostile; that'll make me not want to help you in the future. CodeReview can help you improve your systems. "Idea" isn't what this site is for; its for a specific answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new Thread for every new client.

```java
public class Server extends Thread {

     ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

            while (true) {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                (new FileSaver(s)).start();

            }
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

    ...
}
```

```java
public class FileSaver extends Thread {

    Socket socket;

    public FileSaver(Socket socket) {
        socket = socket;
    }

    public saveFile() {
        // save the file here
    };

    public void run() {
        saveFile();
    }

}
```